# how to reference class constant using variable

Tags: ruby

I have a class:

```
class VoteType < MyModel
    UPVOTE          = where(slug: "up-vote").pluck(:id).first
    DOWNVOTE        = where(slug: "down-vote").pluck(:id).first
    FAVORITE        = where(slug: "favorite").pluck(:id).first
    SPAM                = where(slug: "spam").pluck(:id).first
end
```

If I have a variable like this:

`myVar = "UPVOTE"`

How can I reference the constant in the class using the variable? I tried the following which doesn't work:

```
VoteType::send(myVar)
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a variable like `myVar`. It should be `my_var`. This is Ruby, where we embrace snake_case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below:

```
VoteType.const_get(myVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Constants are not methods, and send *only* works with methods.

Use [`Module#const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get) to access constants, e.g.

```
VoteType.const_get('UPVOTE')
```

Answer (score -2):

Is "eval" work for you?

```
a = "aaaaaa"
b = 'a'
c = eval b
puts c
```

Output is:  aaaaaa